# How to make a program always run in non-elevated in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I have some **elevated** programs that open Firefox. However, I don't want Firefox to run as an elevated process because when I try to open links from **non-elevated** programs later, it doesn't open in Firefox. The only way I can make Firefox "retain" it's non-elevated state is if I had it open **before** I open the links from the elevated programs. I want to go a step further and make it so that when an elevated program tries to open a link in Firefox even if Firefox is closed, Firefox will get launched in non-elevated state. How do I do this? In other words, I want Firefox to run in **non-elevated** state no matter what.

Comment: This is the default behavior for any application that does not indicate otherwise.  If the program is starting Firefox with elevated permissions the it specifically is elevating the permission on Firefox when it does it

Comment: And, the launcher program can use a workaround here. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643 (Note: Info in that article is for developers.) to start non-elevated process using shellexecute

Comment: @Ramhound the programs that open Firefox aren't even required to be elevated to begin with. I just set them to Run as Administrator for compatibility purposes so in essence they should not require Firefox (or any browser) to be running as administrator at all.

Comment: @w32sh so I'd have to make a launcher program for Firefox and then set that program as the default "browser" instead?

Comment: If you can't modify the original program's code for some reason, then yes, a stub or launcher tool is another option.

Comment: Do you have any links to help with making my launcher be treated by Windows 10 as a "browser" so to speak?

Comment: Basically, you'd have to follow the [Default Programs registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) procedure described at the MSDN...And your program should take care of the launch part using command-line arguments.